# Mask minimum values in matrix rows

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, masking, minimum

I have this 3x3 matrix:

```
a=array([[ 1, 11,  5],
   [ 3,  9,  9],
   [ 5,  7, -3]])
```

I need to mask the minimum values in each row in order to calculate the mean of each row discarding the minimum values. Is there a general solution? 
I have tried with

```
a_masked=np.ma.masked_where(a==np.ma.min(a,axis=1),a)
```

Which masks the minimum value in first and third row, but not the second row?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the comparison `a == a.min(axis=1)` is comparing each *column* to the minimum value of each row rather than comparing each row to the minimum values. This is because `a.min(axis=1)` returns a vector rather than a matrix which behaves similarly to an `Nx1` array. As such, when broadcasting, the `==` operator performs the operation in a column-wise fashion to match dimensions.

```
a == a.min(axis=1)

# array([[ True, False, False],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

One potential way to fix this is to `resize` the result of `a.min(axis=1)` into column vector (e.g. a 3 x 1 2D array).

```
a == np.resize(a.min(axis=1), [a.shape[0],1])

# array([[ True, False, False],
#        [ True, False, False],
#        [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Or more simply as @ColonelBeuvel has shown:

```
a == a.min(axis=1)[:,None]
```

Now applying this to your entire line of code.

```
a_masked = np.ma.masked_where(a == np.resize(a.min(axis=1),[a.shape[0],1]), a)

# masked_array(data =
#   [[-- 11 5]
#   [-- 9 9]
#   [5 7 --]],
#        mask =
#           [[ True False False]
#            [ True False False]
#            [False False  True]],
#           fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It works now, thanks to @Colonel Beauvel as well

Comment: I have an additional question actually. What if i have a row with two or three of the same elements, for example: a=array([[ 7, 5,  5],
   [ 3,  6,  9],
   [ 5,  1, 1]])

How can i only mask one of the minimum value and not them all?

Comment: Can u help me as well? @ColonelBeuvel

Answer (score 0):

What is with the min() function?

For every Row just do min(row) and it gives you the minimum of this list in your Case a row. Simply append this minimum in a list for all Minimum.

minList=[]

`for i in array:
    minList.append(min(i))`

Comment: No, no, and no. For loop are "forbidden" for such operations.

Comment: Can u help me in the comments section above in the other answer? @ColonelBeuvel